Customize page with character top and half different color (with TikZ or other solution)
Im trying to make a custom chapterpage and my aim is to get a page in which:

the bottom 1/3 pageheight is filled gray
then a character should middle/center aligned around 2/3 pageheight, with: 1) the top half in gray and 2) the bottom half in white and 3) it should be left-aligned such that it aligns with the page-margin.

Below is an example of what I want, and this is the code I made myself, but setting the fontsize does not work and the text is not left-aligned but center aligned around "box.north west" and then shifted. This is not what I want, ha!
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        % Bottom 1/3 of page gray
        \node[fill=darkgray, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=0.33333\paperheight, anchor=south west, line width=0mm] (box) at (current page.south west) {};
        % Bottom part of character
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (box.north west) rectangle ++(10cm,10cm);
            \node[anchor=center, align=left, color=darkgray, font=\fontsize{160}{200}\selectfont, xshift=180pt] (text) at (box.north west) {1};
        \end{scope}
        % Top of character
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (box.north east) rectangle (text.south west);
            \node[anchor=north west, align=left, color=white, font=\fontsize{160}{200}\selectfont] (text2) at (text.north west) {1};
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Thanks in advance of course!

For the font size: it works if you choose a font which has the size or a scaleable font. Try for example with \usepackage{lmodern}

As Sam Carter indicated, the issue with the size of the digit is to do with the use of a font which is only available at fixed sizes. That comment suggested switching to a scaleable font and suggested Latin Modern. That should work, but you don't have to change fonts to get scaleable ones as Computer Modern is available in scaleable form, too. If you switch the font encoding to T1, you will get the scaleable postscript type1 versions by default.
However, this is not sufficient. Although the fonts themselves are scaleable, the way they are set up for LaTeX isn't. Hence, for anything over 35.38pt or so, you get 35.38pt. Since they are scaleable, however, good results can be obtained by scaling them.
There are two ways to do this. First, you could override the default font settings or create new ones. However, that is not really necessary for this usage. It is simpler to just have tikz do the scaling. To do this, we make sure we use the largest available size as the base, because this will give the best quality results. We then just use scale=<factor>. I used 5 because that approximates the 160pt target (very roughly), but you can tweak this for an exact match if desired.
The alignment issue just needs some slight modifications to anchor and some attention to the padding all nodes get by default.
Note that Computer Modern uses tabular figures by default, so they are set up to ensure every digit has the same width. This means an aligned 1 may not look aligned to the left margin because its bounding box is wider than the visible glyph. If you want to avoid this, use proportional figures instead or manually adjust the placement.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  % Bottom 1/3 of page gray
  \node[fill=darkgray, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=0.33333\paperheight, anchor=south west, line width=0mm] (box) at (current page.south west) {};
  % Bottom part of character
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (box.north west) rectangle ++(10cm,10cm);
    \node[anchor=west, color=darkgray, font=\fontsize{35.83}{35.83}\selectfont, xshift=\oddsidemargin+1in, inner sep=0pt, scale=5] (text) at (box.north west) {1};
  \end{scope}
  % Top of character
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (box.north east) rectangle (text.south west);
    \node[anchor=north west, color=white, inner sep=0pt, font=\fontsize{35.83}{35.83}\selectfont,scale=5] (text2) at (text.north west) {1};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Edit
Here's a recommendation for a method which avoids remember picture and produces the correct output in a single compilation. This also means the tikzpicture can be externalised to conserve resources and speed compilation.
The output is just the same and the content of the picture is very similar. Only the reference point and the method of producing the image are different. \mbox{} is just to give TeX something to ship out, triggering the hook.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\AddToHook{shipout/background}{%
  \put (0pt,-\paperheight) {%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      % Bottom 1/3 of page gray
      \node[fill=darkgray,minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=0.33333\paperheight, anchor=south west, line width=0mm] (box) at (0pt,0pt) {};
      % Bottom part of character
      \begin{scope}
        \clip (box.north west) rectangle ++(10cm,10cm);
        \node[anchor=west, color=darkgray, font=\fontsize{35.83}{35.83}\selectfont, xshift=\oddsidemargin+1in, inner sep=0pt, scale=5] (text) at (box.north west) {1};
      \end{scope}
      % Top of character
      \begin{scope}
        \clip (box.north east) rectangle (text.south west);
        \node[anchor=north west, color=white, inner sep=0pt, font=\fontsize{35.83}{35.83}\selectfont,scale=5] (text2) at (text.north west) {1};
      \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
}
\mbox{}

\end{document}


For the life of me I cannot figure out, where the ++(10,10 )  is referenced from, I see the OP provided it, but that clip can be changed to  \draw (box.north west) rectangle ++(0,0);. Can you explain to me as if you talking to a plotter, ie move here etc. I always have trouble figuring how tikz decides to draw in remember picture.

@yannisl I replied in chat. I think I pinged you, but I'm not totally sure.

Fantastic, thanks a lot!
